# LibGDX/Java: Only sort objects from another Array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting, libgdx

I'm sorting my Array 30 times per second(the y-values of the objects). Now, to improve performance I only want to sort the objects whose position changed.
I put them in a list and clear the list after sorting.
But how do I only sort those objects and not the full Array?

```
 public CustomOrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(TiledMap map, final GameScreen gameScreen) {
        super(map);
        this.gameScreen = gameScreen;
        pComparator = new Comparator<Object>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object object, Object t1) {
                float p1 = object.rectangle.getY();
                float p2 = t1.rectangle.getY();
                if (p1 > p2) {
                    return -1; // First bigger
                } else if (p1 < p2) {
                    return 1; // Second bigger
                } else
                    return 0; // They are the same
            }
        };
    }
```

[...]

```
gameScreen.game.tiledMapHandler.objects.sort(...);  //I want to sort all objects from the lastmodifiedobjects list there

gameScreen.game.tiledMapHandler.lastModifiedObjects.clear();


for (Object o : gameScreen.game.tiledMapHandler.objects) {
//render objects
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `List`, then you can first call `subList` to create a view on a range, and then sort the result (e.g., `Collections.sort(x.subList(begin,end(),mycomparator)`).

In you have an array of Objects, Java allows you to sort arrays in a range using [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[],%20int,%20int)).